# Editting CSS in iframe that sets Select tag's text color to black?

Tags: css, xss, google-chrome-extension

This is a very specific question for a Google Chrome extension.

http://www.meebo.com/mobile/

This page is where you're kicked to when you go to Meebo.com on an iPhone or Droid phone. But if you notice, the Status box where you can set yourself away or what you want your status to be has white text on a white background.

In order to get a website to appear in a Google Chrome extension's popup window (the one that drops down when you click the icon next to the address bar) that isn't an included html file in the extension, I need to use an iFrame. I know that there's security measures about Cross-Site stuff like javascript and I'm not surprised I'm having trouble accessing the CSS. But there's a class, status, and it's color is white and I need to change that to black. I've tested it with Chrome's Inspect Element window and if I change that, I'll be fine.

I've tried changing the manifest.json file to inject a CSS file using Content-Scripts, but nothing...

I'm new to Chrome Extensions but I have experience doing web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is to change the DOM inside the iframe, ie to change the style of the text element with javascript.
You can for example, change the 'color' attribute of the text element, or change his CSS class and add a new one.